Migrate to Vite.js but proxy doesn't work
I already migrate from CRA to Vite.js for better developer experience.
After that, the proxy doesn't work.
From the old one version (CRA) it working fine and correctly
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    "/api/sandbox",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "https://my-sandbox-service.com",
      pathRewrite: {
        "/api/sandbox": "",
      },
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
    })
  );

  // So on other proxies ...
}


So, I convert it to vite.config.ts like this
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";
import path from "path";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import viteTsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

export default defineConfig({
  base: "/",
  plugins: [react(), viteTsconfigPaths(), svgr()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets"),
    },
  },
  build: {
    outDir: "build",
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api/sandbox": {
        target: "https://my-sandbox-service.com",
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api\/sandbox/, ""),
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
     },

     // So on other proxies ...
  }
})

for the new one version, it work only when I run on local machine
But not working and I deployed on dev environment.
When I called a request from my website /api/sandbox/v2/auth/login
it should be proxy pass and rewrite to be https://my-sandbox-service.com/v2/auth/login
But it just send a request as https://my-website.com/api/sandbox/v2/auth/login
I don't know why. I try everything.

Does this answer your question? I can't setup proxy in mern stack(react-vite) and do not know the reason

Yes I already try from that post. set secure: false or set rewrite as a regEx. But it not work.
